# MySQL recovery, include binlog position MASTER_LOG_POS

Tags: mysql, mysqlbinlog

I run a MySQL DB dump like this:

```
mysqldump mydatabase -u root -p --single-transaction --events --routines --quick --master-data=2 --flush-logs --flush-privileges > mydump.sql
```

This creates a dump file, which contains the following line:

```
CHANGE MASTER TO MASTER_LOG_FILE='mysql-bin.000008', MASTER_LOG_POS=120;
```

This tells me that any new changes are recorded starting in mysql-bin.000008

I can then, after loading my dump file, load the incremental files like this (assuming  mysql-bin.000009 was also created at some point):

```
mysqlbinlog mysql-bin.000008 mysql-bin.000009 | mysql -u root -p mydatabase
```

**But what about MASTER_LOG_POS = 120?** Do I need to include that and, if so, how? My dump command included --flush-logs so it should have started a brand new file.

I'm reading the here https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/backup-policy.html and here https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/recovery-from-backups.html

Answer (score 1):

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/mysqlbinlog.html#option_mysqlbinlog_start-position says:

> --start-position=N, -j N
>
> Start reading the binary log at the first event having a position
>   equal to or greater than N. This option applies to the first log file
>   named on the command line.
>
> This option is useful for point-in-time recovery.

Comment: But are you sure it's even necessary? The --flush-logs parameter should have started a new binlog, and MySQL's backup/recovery directions don't mention needing to use this info. It just seemed odd to me that it was there, then.